# how can i create two div's next o each other angular

Tags: html, css, angular

i tried to use marging left but still not working can any

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
    <div  height: 100px;  background: green;"> 
        Left Div 
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 50%; height: 100px; background: blue;"> 
        Right Div
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just add to the first child float left and widht 50% and give both of them display inline-block

Answer (score 0):

This is not an Angular problem. By default, `div` elements have the style attribute `display: block` which will place them on their own line/block.

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>Div 1</div>
<div>Div 2</div>
```

If you want them to be side-by-side, you can change their style attribute to `display: inline-block`.

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>Div 1</div>
<div>Div 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use flex

```
<div style="width: 100%; display:flex">
<div  height: 100px;  background: green; width:50%"> 
    Left Div 
</div>
<div style="margin-left: 50%; height: 100px; background: blue;width:50%"> 
    Right Div
</div>
```